# What's the difference between document.get("nested.value"), document.get("nested").value and document.nested.value in Mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, getter

Let's say I have a Schema and object like this:

```
var documentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    simple: { type: String },
    nested: {
        value: { type: Number }
    }
};
```

What is the difference then between the following and which one should I use?

```
console.log( document.nested.value );
console.log( document.get('nested').value );
console.log( document.get('nested.value') );
```

They all produce the same result. I assume I should use `get()` but can someone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-get) can take a second parameter to support dynamic casting, but if you don't need that then there isn't typically a need to use `get` directly as the dot notation is equivalent and cleaner.